Best way to create a map in kotlin from two lists
Apologies if this is a dumb question as I'm pretty sure this is simple, but I'm struggling to find a clean way to create a map from two lists.
I'm pretty sure I could maybe just do a for cycle and iterate through each one but I wanted to check if there is a way to do this that is more visually appealing.
For example:
val list1 = listOf("One", "Two", "Three")
val list2 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
//result would be => {One=1, Two=2, Three=3}


list1.zip(list2).toMap()

Note that having parallel lists in the first place is a bit of a code smell.  (A list of objects is often a better alternative, simplifying cases like this and avoiding risks such as the lists being different lengths.  But of course we can't say anything about your specific case.)

Note: This assumes that you have already checked that both lists contain the same number of elements.
You can use the zip function to create a List<Pair<String, Int>>, then use toMap on the resulting list of pairs. The resulting list of the zip function will have the size of the smaller list.
val list1 = listOf("One", "Two", "Three")
val list2 = listOf(1, 2, 3)

val myMap = list1.zip(list2).toMap()

If you need to apply any transform on either of the terms, you could use associate. As an example, here we are writing the strings to uppercare and incrementing the ints.
val myMap = list1.zip(list2).associate { it.first.uppercase() to it.second + 1 }

